# Creating PDF in Android using PDFBox

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to create PDF through my Android app using `PDFBox` api, but getting the following error:

**`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument`**

I have already included the following jar files in the `classpath` of the project:-

> - pdfbox-1.8.4
> - fontbox-1.8.4

In some posts I read that it is not possible to use pdfbox to create PDFs in Android since it uses awt and swing components which are not available in Android.

If `PDFBox` is not right choice for creating PDFs through Android application then are there any other open source libraries available for performing the same task.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to include commons logging and fontbox jars..

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi            http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pdfbox/fontbox/1.8.2/

Comment: commons-logging-1.1.3-bin.tar.gz Is the one to download?

Comment: in my project i used commons-logging v 1.1.1

Comment: While I don't understand the error message, it won't work for a different reason - pdfbox uses awt components that aren't available on android. Maybe in a few years...

Comment: @Aravinth...I am using commons-logging-1.1.3.jar and pdfbox-1.8.4.jar and this code...but still getting the same error // Create a document and add a page to it
   // Create a new empty document
   PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

   // Create a new blank page and add it to the document
   PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
   document.addPage( blankPage );

   // Save the newly created document
   document.save("BlankPage.pdf");

   // finally make sure that the document is properly
   // closed.
   document.close();

Comment: @TilmanHausherr.. any open source library available for creating PDFs in Android?

Comment: @Aravinth .. you used apache PDF BOX in Android or Java applications?

Comment: @androidDev java applications..

Comment: @Aravinth.. but in the subject itself I have clearly mentioned " Creation of PDF in ANDROID", you should have mentioned in your comment before only.

Comment: @androidDev it is android or java no issue you need to include the required jar to fix above error...and take care...

Comment: @Aravinth I am adding commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, fontBox 1.8.4.jar, pdfbox-1.8.4.jar in the libs folder of the folder, still getting the same error, my code is  PDDocument document = null;
    document= new PDDocument();