# Android and Apache PDFBox

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox

Is Apache PDFBox compatible with Android?

I cannot use iText since it has some kind of licensing associated with it.
If Apache PDFBox is not comptabile with Android then is there any other open source lib available that can be used for Android?

Comment: what exactly do you want to implement?

Comment: @MehulJoisar.. I want to create PDF through my android app

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF Library for Android - PDFBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952626/pdf-library-for-android-pdfbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create pdf using your app,

You can use [PdfDocument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) if your app is for users who have android devices having api 19 or above.

Otherwise you can use open-sourced library named [Android PDF Writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/)

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: but this is available only for API 19 what about the devices which are still supporting API below 19.

Comment: I have tried PDFBox but getting error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290698/creating-pdf-in-android-using-pdfbox

Comment: @androidDev: you can use Android PDF Writer which supports lower versions too.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: crl.android.pdfwriter.PDFWriter I am getting this error when using Android PDF writer

Comment: You need to add that class

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create PDF after 2 weeks effort :-) Can we create  tables also using Android PDF writer

Comment: @androidDev: AFAIK, there is no such implementation in open sourced library Android PDF Writer. You can use iTextPdf library which is commercial library

Comment: I have a android project.I need to add it to pdf viewing funtionality.can anyone tell me how to use pdfbox for this?

Comment: How can I add a hyperlink using PdfDocument of Android framework?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Android Port of PDFBox](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android)([Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27887531/3248593)) and works as a charm