# How to read and display pdf from Byte data in android java and how to pass Byte to pdf in android java

Tags: java, android

%PDF-1.7
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 769 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 1237 0 R/ViewerPreferences 1238 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 11/Kids[ 3 0 R 18 0 R 23 0 R 30 0 R 37 0 R 38 0 R 39 0 R 40 0 R 49 0 R 53 0 R 55 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 9 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/XObject<</Image14 14 0 R/Image16 16 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 907>>
stream
xœµ˜Ykã0Çßþz´™hF§¡š¶[ºPhia–}è–6zlÛôa¿ýŽœƒÄ±]Ú„ˆøÏOiæ/¿%#G€B+Òm=XAÁ{ñþŒ~ˆ—d$&Wâðpryrq*äÑ‘˜žžˆ·V–ÓÛd4ù†IÜ>&#’¿(Œ2lê¤Çžùžó'fÉHŠYqäWGçÉèg*²_âö{2:ã§]3ÎÙå‰ØfÂxLV+ð¦`*PZPDE`»¨ˆè¨3ŽH Ug÷&ž{ãƒMW Ài@×™ÀE$0òî>"Ö`º¯ƒ<"’€Ý'"FL‘5äÝ—"FÌˆFJèŒ˜µ·Üv&ˆ˜µ“áîÎS¢6t„ˆiQk ¦_ ¬)&Çï‹ùãÝýBLS8µfP.ãVœh´35jËIµÙtOÜG2;]@¢N4"Øý5}sœåé•¸|ÍP¦¿C3ÊT:_dc“þÝíà`²-Šèï*½9y·C©œ>ŠÜ=ïÀøÿÐ½jo¹
…ªÆÛu6FJ?C@ï²±MŸæUªã Ž5ÃM/ùŠO_6÷ÌØF§>s‹ËK‹!ÜÕË©Õ µYN¼.ÝzI+[QÍr*+„fÓ†aWdÁ+¡Véég·lœ§ó—0ÅhÇE#¦OELŠÓÂ¿÷Ì®n­èV¤•]Ùj %(¯+=·^±ÓÙ&ô¼}Y‡^‚ËùS =¬µa'„ÄòNt`ëTPÍ¦ÍÝVý»½ƒVòk‹PŸ®Ëê«Ù´UéCeõ5 rŽpw‚²øBà5tW T_ClÞGúPY}
A0ºÏŽ˜Êêk‚–@=Êêkgßc.”Ô”-*Ö>B¹ê@ÀÜB¤PN«C‚fîN13¢uÁ4Bbç-6®k*æ@µuIíeÕFÓ
¾ÝÚ† ¢öÁ¼Üª®ýý9ÞdÕx›â3Ÿþ-ˆÿIþÅ&1ä€%D
‰ä­rŽT;j?Gv¢¿UÑ$ÈðÉÙ«–[ÇEúK(éŽáQQª}ÿ4Ôÿr8¥†¼Å†¤Ÿâ¨“kçd¿‡;å²Ø¤ë÷b‡n·œ£3@…G+Y³$–g‰÷á-úÅóÝìµ8}Ë®(Î2VXÀŠÑ¬  uÔHÈýöDZ]]Û1Ûz²]=¹àÿî¨Ò
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/Name/F1/BaseFont/BCDEEE+Calibri/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 6 0 R/FirstChar 32/LastChar 121/Widths 1227 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/BCDEEE+Calibri/Flags 32/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 750/Descent -250/CapHeight 750/AvgWidth 521/MaxWidth 1743/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/StemV 52/FontBBox[ -503 -250 1240 750] /FontFile2 1225 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type/ExtGState/BM/Normal/ca 1>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Type/ExtGState/BM/Normal/CA 1>>
endobj

like this i am getting response data from API and i need to show pdf in app , please tell me how to do , thanks in advance

Comment: Just save the bytes to file.

Comment: You can use PdfDocument [check this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23380612/8644685)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: see i am getting the response like the above , so that response is in bytes, so i want to show the pdf file from those response ,